# How can I consider word dependence along with the semantic information in information retrieval?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, text-mining, information-retrieval, word-embedding

I am working on a project that text retrieval is an important part of it. There is a reference collection (D), and users can enter queries (Q). Therefore, like a search engine, the goal is to retrieve the most related documents to each query.

I used pre-trained word embeddings to extract semantic knowledge about each word within a text. I then aggregated the continuous vectors of words to represent each text as a vector (using mean/sum aggregate function). Next, I indexed the source vectors and extracted the most similar vectors to the query vector. However, the result was not acceptable. I also tested the traditional approaches like the BOW technique. While these approaches work very well in some situations, they do not consider semantic and syntactic information (that made them not good for some queries).

Based on my investigation, considering word dependence (for example, co-occurring the words in the same sentence) along with the semantic information (obtained using the pre-trained word embeddings) can be very useful. However, I do not know how to combine them to be applicable in IR.

It should be noted that:

- I'm not looking for paragraph2vec or doc2vec; those require training on a large data corpus, and I don't have a large data corpus. Instead, I want to use an existing word embeddings.
- I'm not looking for a re-ranking technique like learning to rank approach. Instead, **I'm looking for a way to take advantage of both syntactic and semantic information in the representation step i.e. mapping the text or query to a feature vector.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how many words are there in a text? multiple sentences? A data sample could help to better understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you. The source documents are long, an average of 300 sentences per document. I also tried to segment the text. It improved the results, but there is a need for better result.

Comment: You could try to implement the idea of my paper... https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2766462.2767780

Comment: Thank you @Debasis. I already read your interesting paper. Could you please share your source code, There are still some points that are not completely clear for me.

Comment: here is the code... https://github.com/gdebasis/wvlm a word of caution: i don't maintain this anymore...